# How to get a variable colorbar in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I modified the last example "Colorbar with custom extension lengths" from https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)

cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['royalblue', 'cyan',
                                  'yellow', 'orange'])

bounds = [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
cb3 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap,
                                norm=norm,
                                boundaries= bounds,
                                ticks=bounds,
                                spacing='uniform',
                                orientation='horizontal')
cb3.set_label('Custom extension lengths, some other units')
fig.show()
```

I want to be able to make the bounds array of variable length.
It works for four or three elements e.g.

```
bounds = [-1.0,  0.0, 1.0]
```

but for just two elements in bounds e.g.

```
bounds = [-1.0, 1.0]
```

I get a error: "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero"
Can somebody tell me why I get this error and how to get rid of it?

Maybe it is due to this line

```
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
```

because scalefac = (self.Ncmap - 1) / (self._N - 1) --> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero is part of the error information. However, I don´t understand this information at the moment.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the implementation of `BoundaryNorm` which isn't really meant to work with two bounds (so just one region). You could work around the bug with `BoundaryNorm(bounds, 1 if len(bounds)==2 else cmap.N)`. Note that if you would always use `len(bounds)-1` as the second parameter of `BoundaryNorm`, you would just get the first few colors in the colormap instead of them being evenly spread out. So, the bug is matplotlib trying to evenly spreading out the colors, which should be skipped when there is just one color needed.

Comment: Thank you, if I´m working around the bug with BoundaryNorm(bounds, 1 if len(bounds)==2 else cmap.N) ,  I don´t get the ZeroDivisionError any more. But, if I´m adding now a plot to the colorbar, the color of the plot is royalblue while the color in the colorbar is cyan. However, for more than two bounds this solution works fine.

Comment: Thanks. So, the workaround should be to set the list in `ListedColormap` to have just one color in that case. Something like `if len(bounds) == 2: cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['cyan']` and just using `cmap.N` as the parameter to `BoundaryNorm`